# Can a Service in one APK "hear" an Activity resuming in another APK?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am writing an application that acts as a proxy to a bluetooth peripheral device.  It is designed to allow multiple, third-party applications to connect to it via AIDL interfaces.  In this proxy application, I would like to know when one Activity, within a separate APK, pauses (i.e. goes to the background) and another resumes (i.e. comes to the foreground).  Said another way, I would like to listen for Activity (or Application) pause/resume events which are external to the APK I am running in.

Is there a way to do this in 4.4?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only be able to know the current lifecycle state of an `Activity` on a different process if the app exposes that information (i.e. using a `BroadcastReceiver`).